# Passing mouseover through element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm working on a regex-analyzer that has syntax highlighting as a feature.

My site uses an overlay of two contenteditable divs.

[image]

Because of the difficulty in getting the cursor position and maintaining that even as tags are added and subtracted, I decided the best route was to have two contenteditable divs, one on top of the other. The first (`#rInput`) is pretty plain. If not for some nuisance problems that made me switch from a textarea, it could be a textarea. The second (`#rSyntax`) gets its value from `rInput` and provides syntax highlighting. I make sure that both are always scrolled to the same position so that the overlay is perfect (However, I also use a transparent (`rgba(...)`) font on `rSyntax`, so that if a momentary sync-delay should occur, the text is still legible.)

In the lower portion snapshot above, the code of the contenteditable `rSyntax` is this:

```
<span class="cglayer">(test<span class="cglayer">(this)</span>string)</span>
```

While `rInput`, positioned exactly on top, contains only this

```
(test(this)string)
```

The problem with this method is that I want to offer some alt-tooltips (or a javascript version) when a user mouses over. When the user mouses over `rInput`, I would like to pass the mouseover event to elements of `rSyntax`.

I'd like mousing over `(test ... string)` to show "Capturing group 1", while mousing over `(this)` would show "Capturing group 2", or if it were `(?:test)`, it would say "Non-capturing group".

The terminology is a little tough because searching for things like "above" and "below" pulls up a lot of results that have nothing to do with `z-index`.

I did find the css property `pointer-events` which sounded ideal for the briefest moment but doesn't allow you to filter pointer events (set `rInput` to receive clicks, scrolls, but pass `mouseover` through to `rSyntax` and its child-elements.

I found `document.elementFromPoint` which may offer a solution but I'm not really sure how. I thought I would try `document.getElementById('rInput').getElementFromPoint(mouseX,mouseY)`, but this function is not available to child elements.

Theoretically, I could hide the `rInput` on mousemove, using a setTimeout to put it back quickly, and then a tooltip should appear when mousing over child elements of `rSyntax`, but that doesn't seem like the best solution because I don't want `rSyntax` to be clickable. Clicks should always go to `rInput`.

It's possible to disable the mouseover wizardry while `rInput` has the focus, but then tooltips from `rSyntax` won't work, and though I haven't tried this method, I'm not sure if passing a click event from `rSyntax` to `rInput` would position the cursor properly.

Is there a method to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

The best solution was to move the syntax highlighter `rSyntax` to an iframe because then I can pass `elementFromPoint()` without flickering the div which really is a vast improvement.

```
$(document).on("mousemove", "#rInput", function (e) {
    $element = $(document.getElementById('frSyntax').contentDocument.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY));
    if ($element.attr("id") != "frSyntax" && $element.attr("id") != "rSyntax" && $element.attr("title") && $element.attr("title").length) {
        $mother.find(".dashed").removeClass("dashed")
        $element.addClass("dashed")
        $("#syntip").html($element.attr("title"))
        $("#syntip").css({"top": e.pageY+10, "left": e.pageX, "display": "inline-block"})
    } else {
        $mother.find(".dashed").removeClass("dashed");
        $("#syntip").hide()
    }
})
```

And at the beginning of my `$(document).ready(...`, I added this

```
$('#frSyntax').load(function(){
    $mother = $("#frSyntax").contents();
    //frSyntax is the name of the iframe.
    $syntax = $mother.find("#rSyntax")
});
```

### First Solution

#### I'll leave this here in case it's more like what someone wants.

From further research, I feel like the only approach is `mousemove` wizardry making the element disappear, finding the element below, with `document.elementFromPosition`, and popping it back in.

I'm still looking for advice if anyone has a better option.

The trouble is that this "flickering" will cause `mousemove` and `mouseover` to keep triggering, which is needless. So I created a variable to log the coords and only apply a change when the mouse actually moved.

```
$(document).on("mousemove", "#rInput", function (e) {
    if (holdmouse != (e.pageX + "," + e.pageY)) {
        $("#rInput").hide();
        element = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY));
        if (element.attr("id") != "rInput" && element.attr("id") != "rSyntax") {
            $(".classes, .cglayer").css("border-bottom","none");
            element.css("border-bottom","2px dashed black")
            $("#syntip").html(element.attr("title"))
            $("#syntip").css({"top": e.pageY+10, "left": e.pageX, "display": "inline-block"})
            holdmouse = e.pageX + "," + e.pageY
        } else {
            $(".classes, .cglayer").css("border-bottom","none");
            $("#syntip").hide()
        }
        $("#rInput").show()
    }
})
```